# Ignore hidden elements in a table cell using DataTables button Print

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables with Buttons extension. I have **Print** button as could be seen in [this example](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html).

My table:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Active</th>
            <th class="text-center">Pipeline</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>121<span class="hidden">Hidden Text</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

But it shows in print preview window and on paper:

```
Active Pipeline
100    121 Hidden Text
```

I want it to be printed as:

```
Active Pipeline
100    121
```

How can I exclude elements with class `hidden` from being printed?

Comment: `.hidden{
    display:none;
}` to css or `style='display:none'` in the html

Comment: `$('.hidden').hide();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

By default jQuery DataTables strips HTML when preparing print preview window. That is why CSS rules are not being applied and hidden text is shown in print preview window and on paper.

> **SOLUTION**

You need to customize DataTables print button and use `stripHtml: false` option, see sample code below:

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
       {
           extend: 'print',
           exportOptions: {
               stripHtml: false
           }               
       }        
    ]      
} );
```

I assume you have the following CSS rule to hide elements with class `hidden`.

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/watwtc15/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: i tried with datatables but yet it is printing  showing same above behavior in ui it is hide.

Comment: @arunkumar, I think I understand what you mean now, you're using Print button from [this example](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html). My solution will not work, let me see if there is alternative solution.